# Asp.Net C# get checkbox value of "this" checked checkbox without looping

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, this

I have hundreds of checkboxes that are dynamically created with different values. They are all the same id. I am using asp.net c# checkbox.

Without looping through all of the checkboxes, I'd like to only deal with the checkbox I actually click. Basically, the same behavior you would get using JQuery $(this).val(); for example.

I know this can be done using Jquery but I need to do it with C#. I'm trying to figure how to do the equivalent of the code below in C#.

```
$('.maingrid input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
   var value = $(this).next("label").text();
   console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "`They are all the same id`" ? ...

Comment: You probably want to revise the shared `id`s. For grouping to determine which one/s were checked at postback, you would want to give them the same `name`, for styling consistency, you would give them the same `class`, but the `id` is meant to be unique - it is after all, as its name suggests, an identifier. If you can't identify something using its identifier, what use is the identifier?

Comment: I'm not using regular html checkbox. It is dot.net (<asp:CheckBox ID="cboxList"). The checkbox is inside a GridView so after rows are put out you end up with IDs like ctl00_ctl00_MasterContent_contentMain_GridView1_ctl07_cboxList. That's all I meant by the same ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an event handler and set the checkboxes `onCheckedChanged` [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event to that event handler.  When the event is called, cast the `sender` to a CheckBox in to a var and go from there.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I'm new to C# and was having trouble with the syntax. I will check the link you sent.